# Control de acceso mediante IP a aplicación Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Quiero **controlar el acceso a mi webapp mediante IP**, usando una ***lista blanca de IPs***, es decir, solamente las *IPs registradas* en la base de datos tienen acceso, el resto deben retornar una vista.

Estuve leyendo un poco acerca de eso e hice este controlador y su respectiva vista, pero me da error.

Tengo una tabla llamada `acceso_remoto` que dentro tiene las columnas `id_acceso` y `ip_publica`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class InicioController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

       if($ip == DB::table('acesso_remoto')->where('ip_publica')->get();($acceso))
       {

        return redirect()->route('inicio');

       }

       return view('acceso');
    }
```

Comment: Que error te da? Estas tomando en cuenta que para acceder al método `index` en el constructor del controlador usas `$this->middleware('auth');` es decir que debes tener iniciada una sesión.

Comment: Asi es quiero que redireccione a una vista aun despues de que inicie sesion, el error que muestra es syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: En el `if` comparas `$ip` == `DB::table('acesso_remoto')->where('ip_publica')->get();($acceso)` por eso el error. Usando middleware como la respuesta que agregaron es mejor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si se desea controlar el acceso, lo mejor es crear un middleware.

Crear el Middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckIpAccess
```

Registrar el Middleware en `App\Http\Kernel.php` , dentro del array  `$routeMiddleware` , con el nombre como clave y como valor la ruta de la clase.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    ....

    'checkip' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckIpAccess::class 
];
```

En el `middleware` agregamos la lógica que ya tenía casi terminada en el controlador, puede obtener la dirección `IP` con PHP con `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` pero si usa Laravel puede utilizar el método [ip()](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ip) que posee la clase `Request`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   //$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   //Otra opción
   $ip = request()->ip(); 
   $acceso = DB::table('acesso_remoto')->where('acesso_remoto',$ip)->first();
   if(is_null($acceso)){ // si es null, es porque no existe y retornamos la ruta
     return redirect()->route('acceso');
   }
   //caso contrario seguimos con petición
   return $next($request);
}
```

Ahora desde las rutas puede hacer uso del `middleware`,

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->middleware('checkip'); //
```

O un grupo de rutas

```
 /* ruta para mostrar la vista acceso cuando no exista la ip*/
 Route::get('acceso', function () {
  return view('accesso');
})->name('acceso');

Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['auth','checkip']], function () {
   /** más rutas*/

})
```

Comment: realice todos los pasos pero me sale el error "Call to a member function setCookie() on null"

Comment: @AbdielHernandez he actualizado mi respuesta. Sí tiene problemas con mi respuesta, hace bien en comentar.

Comment: ya investigue y quedo resuelto muchas gracias! al imprimir la variable $ip veo que no devuelve la ip publica si no ":::1" lo que provoca que no haga match con la base de datos, como puedo guardar la ip publica en la variable $ip que esta dentro de el middleware checkIpAccess?

Comment: @AbdielHernandez sí no es muy confiable `REMOTE_ADDR` , igual Laravel le facilita el acceso a la clase `Request` y su método `ip()` como añadí en mi respuesta, verifiqué si funciona ;)